# Custom Map annotation doesn't work using @Published

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit, combine

cI am using SwiftUI and custom annotations. Everything works ok if I pass an array of custom annotations `MapCustomAnnotation` directly from my `View`. However, when I try to fetch data from my local server the annotations are not shown even though the `@Published` array contains correct data. Here is the code:

```
struct MyMapView<ViewModel: MyViewModeling & ObservableObject>: View {
    
        @ObservedObject private var viewModel: ViewModel
    
        init(viewModel: ViewModel) {
            self.viewModel = viewModel
        }
    
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                MapView(region: getRegion(), annotation: viewModel.mapCustomAnnotations)
                    .onAppear(perform: viewModel.viewAppeared)
            }
        }
}
```

View Model

```
protocol MyViewModeling {
    // other stuff
    var mapCustomAnnotations: [MapCustomAnnotation] { get set }
}

final class MyViewModel: MyViewModeling & ObservableObject {
  
     //other stuff

    // MARK: - Published Properties

    @Published var mapCustomAnnotations: [MapCustomAnnotation] = [MapCustomAnnotation]()

   //other stuff to inject service etc etc 

    func fetchEvents() {
        Task(priority: .utility) { // CHANGED IT AS SUGGESTED 
            let result = await self.service.getEventsForTypeWithMinAndMaxCoordinates(minCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -2.323_24, longitude: 76.434_343_4), maxCoordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -12.009_090, longitude: 75.434_535_3))
            switch result {
            case let .success(response):
               await MainActor.run {  // CHANGED IT AS SUGGESTED 
                  //getMapPinViewModel simply initialize and append the MapCustomAnnotation objects from my model 
                  mapCustomAnnotations = self.getMapPinViewModel(events: response.data)
                }
            case let .failure(error):
                print(error.customMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has I said, setting a breakpoint inside my view, I can see that MapView is called again once the @Published array is updated but I cannot see the annotations> Everything works if I passed the following array directly in the view:

```
    let data = [MapCustomAnnotation(name: "place1", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.901_784, longitude: 12.426_366), type: .football),
 MapCustomAnnotation(name: "place2", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.900_784, longitude: 12.426_366), type: .volley)]
```

Do I need to trigger the view update somehow?

Comment: You should not combine async/await tasks with DispatchQueue.  If you need to execute on the main queue from within a `Task`, use `await MainActor.run{}`.  Also you shouldn't use `.background` priority - There is a risk of starvation.  `.utility` or `.userInitiated` are better choices.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you so much for your advice! I am new to `await/async` as I was using Future and Combine before. I will definitely change that! Thanks again!

Comment: you shouldn't use an async/await `Task` inside Combine's `ObservableObject`. Use the `.task` or `.task(id:)` modifier instead.